# How to run code remotely using google cloud VM and a cronjob

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cron, python-3.10

I have a folder /scrapers containing 4 scrapers and a runnner.py file which runs the code, as well as a firebase-sdk.json file containing my firebase database information.
I have been trying to set up a cronjob to run the code every 1 minute to run the scrapers which adds new news stories to a firebase realtime database
I have a VM set up in google cloud computing engine but my code does not seem to be running.
I am fairly inexperienced with this kind of thing so any help would be appreciated. I can provide more information if I have left anything out
I was trying crontab -e and this is what I was using inside the crontab file

```
MAILTO = ""
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3 runner.py
```

Comment: You must specify the full path for **runner.py**. The dependencies must be installed globally as there is no **user** account. Review the **cron** log files for error messages.

Comment: ive entered the full path. How would I access the logs? ive been googling it for the past while but i cant seem to see the same files as are present in my VM

Comment: Your question does not show the full path just **runner.py**. Log location depends on OS. For some it is **/var/log/syslog**. Do you have Google Cloud Logging setup? https://cloud.google.com/logging This article might help you, there are many more on the Internet: https://www.baeldung.com/linux/cron-job-testing-debugging